# Extract timeframe from factor datetime - R

Tags: r, datetime, time, timer

I have this sample code (it's a factor data type):

```
> head(df$Timeframe_x1)
[1] 30/12/1899 13:12:59 30/12/1899 12:59:20 30/12/1899 11:58:26 30/12/1899 11:15:45
[5] 30/12/1899 04:17:14 30/12/1899 03:08:34
```

How can I transform it to timer values (hours, minutes, or seconds) in a efficient way, and given that this timer starts at `30/12/1899 00:00:00` which means 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds accumulated?

This is my current code:

```
z <- dmy_hms(df$Timeframe_x1)
df$Hours <- hour(z)
df$Minutes <- minute(z)
df$Seconds <- second(z)
df$TotalSeconds <- df$Hours*3600 + df$Minutes*60 + df$Seconds
```

It works but I'm looking for a more efficient one as I have to apply it to 65 columns (`df$timeframe_x1` to `df$timeframe_x65`) and not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to do this

```
nm1 <- paste0("Timeframe_x", 1:65)
df[nm1] <- lapply(df[nm1], f1)
```

where `f1` is the function

```
f1 <- function(x) {
   z <- dmy_hms(x)
   Hours <- hour(z)
   Minutes <- minute(z)
   Seconds <- second(z)
   Hours*3600 + Minutes*60 + Seconds     
}
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
    mutate_at(vars(nm1), f1)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, f1), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difftime` and `lubridate::seconds_to_period` to get the difference in time for your timer values. `dplyr::mutate_at` can be a good option to use as OP has mentioned that he got more than 65 columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Start time for Timer
start_time <- dmy_hms("30/12/1899 00:00:00")

df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("T")), dmy_hms) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("T")), 
  funs(Timer = seconds_to_period(difftime(. , start_time, units = "secs"))))

#   ID                  T1                  T2    T1_Timer    T2_Timer
# 1  1 1899-12-30 13:12:59 1899-12-30 13:12:59 13H 12M 59S 13H 12M 59S
# 2  2 1899-12-30 12:59:20 1899-12-30 12:59:20 12H 59M 20S 12H 59M 20S
# 3  3 1899-12-30 11:58:26 1899-12-30 11:58:26 11H 58M 26S 11H 58M 26S
# 4  4 1899-12-30 11:15:45 1899-12-30 11:15:45 11H 15M 45S 11H 15M 45S
# 5  5 1899-12-30 04:17:14 1899-12-30 04:17:14  4H 17M 14S  4H 17M 14S
# 6  6 1899-12-30 03:08:34 1899-12-30 03:08:34   3H 8M 34S   3H 8M 34S
```

**Data:** Sample data.

```
Timeframe_x1 <- c("30/12/1899 13:12:59", "30/12/1899 12:59:20", "30/12/1899 11:58:26",
"30/12/1899 11:15:45", "30/12/1899 04:17:14", "30/12/1899 03:08:34")


df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, T1 = Timeframe_x1, T2 = Timeframe_x1)

df
# ID                  T1                  T2
# 1  1 30/12/1899 13:12:59 30/12/1899 13:12:59
# 2  2 30/12/1899 12:59:20 30/12/1899 12:59:20
# 3  3 30/12/1899 11:58:26 30/12/1899 11:58:26
# 4  4 30/12/1899 11:15:45 30/12/1899 11:15:45
# 5  5 30/12/1899 04:17:14 30/12/1899 04:17:14
# 6  6 30/12/1899 03:08:34 30/12/1899 03:08:34
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ ID: int  1 2 3 4 5 6
# $ T1: Factor w/ 6 levels "30/12/1899 03:08:34",..: 6 5 4 3 2 1
# $ T2: Factor w/ 6 levels "30/12/1899 03:08:34",..: 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Note:** I have changed column names to `T1` and `T2` for simplicity in displaying solution in SO.